# Web scraping using beautiful soup (sports data)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When i try loading this code i get two errors.
1:The first one is that i can't properly scrape the data for name_text.

2: I get an indentation error for team = name_text.div.text. I know it is probably easy to solve but i have tried different indentations and nothing seems to be working.

in the website I am wanting to scrape the team name and the odds.

```
<div class="size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24vo participantText_fivg86r" data-automation-id="participant-one">Orlando Magic</div>
<div class="priceText_f71sibe"><span class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9" data-automation-id="price-text">5.85</span></div>
```

The html above has been copied from the site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = 'https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/basketball-us'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

price_text = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
name_text = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24vo participantText_fivg86r"})
filename = "odds.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "Team, odds_team\n"
print(name_text)
f.write(headers)

for price_text in price_texts:
team = name_text.div.text
odds = price_text.span.text

print(odds)
print(team + odds)
f.write(team + "," + odds + "\n")
f.close()
```

Any help would be great. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for loop` indentation is not correct. The correct indentation would be:

```py
for price_text in price_texts:
    team = name_text.div.text
    odds = price_text.span.text
    team = name_text.div.text
    odds = price_text.span.text

    print(odds)
    print(team + odds)
    f.write(team + "," + odds + "\n")
f.close()
```

With 4 spaces before team and odds. Please read the [Python ForLoop documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Also, there is no `price_texts` variable. You need to assign it when you do *findAll*, you forgot an 'S':

```py
price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
```

Last thing, consider using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) instead of `open()` and `.close()` to write to your file.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The looping is making more sense now. Is there a reason you have repeated  team = name_text.div.text and odds = price_text.span.text?

I get an error when i get to the line team = name_text.div.text. The error states that the name 'name_text' is not defined but i don't get why because i have done the similar process for odds and it works fine for odds.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking what you could do is just iterate and store those into lists, then write to file. I unfortunately can't access the site at work, so I can't test the code, but I believe this should give the output you are looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

my_url = 'https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/basketball-us'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

price_text = soup.findAll("span",{"data-automation-id":"price-text"})
name_text = soup.findAll("div",{"data-automation-id":"participant-one"})

team_list = [ name.text.strip() for name in name_text ]
odds_list = [ price.text.strip() for price in price_text ]

d = [team_list, odds_list]
export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')
with open('odds.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      wr.writerow(("Team", "odds_team"))
      wr.writerows(export_data)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: This is way above my ability but does work error free. However, it doesn't produce a list of team names. Header 1 has no names underneath, but header 2 does have the odds underneath.

Comment: Ok. I’ll adjust it when I get into work. Like I said though, can access the site. Make sure the findAll for the teams is correctly grabbing the team names. Another possibility is there’s white space. So I’ll edit that in now, but like I said will give a deeper look in a bit.

Comment: Looking at the OP, I’d probably choose to use the data-automation-id, instead of class. Like I said, I’ll fix the code in a bit, and explain each bit so you u derstand what it’s doing.

Comment: @mclo I made an edit to the code. try it and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = 'https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/basketball-us'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
name_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24voparticipantText_fivg86r"})
filename = "odds.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "Team, odds_team\n"
print(name_text)
f.write(headers)

odds =''
team=''
for price_text in price_texts:
    odds = price_text.text
for name_text in name_texts:
    team = name_text.text
print(odds)
print(team + odds)
f.write(team + "," + odds + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: This almost works. It gets an error
NameError: name 'team' is not defined. 
It's the same error as the response above. I am stumped. This project is too advanced for someone learning basic python.

Comment: my bad. you have to define team and odds before the for loops. I've edited it